# Scala sort string based on length of the tokens

Tags: scala

I have the following List

```
val input = List("Rahul KM","M Ranjan","LK Advani")
```

I want to sort this list splitted values based on string length.
For example I need the output to be like

```
op
List("Rahul KM","Ranjan M","Advani LK")
```

Edit: For Example consider "LK Advani", I need this sorted to "Advani LK" as len(Advani) > len(LK)

Comment: Two minutes spent reading the Scaladoc for `List` would have shown you `sortBy` The example there even uses `length`.

Comment: I not just sorting by length. I am moving the initials around

Comment: I didn't down vote, but perhaps for an example that didn't match the question you (initially) asked. Moving the initials about has no connection with sorting by length (the length doesn't change),  and so what _is_ your actual question? Sorting by length, or moving the initials? If the latter, I have no idea what "moving the Initials based on length"  means...

Comment: AH OK, so that's clearer after another edit. The List is therefore irrelevant. You're asking how to sort the words in  a String into length order

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the right algorithm? What will you do when you get people with a surname of "Ng"? (quite common)

Comment: We are trying to use a phonetic based algorithm to work on the string. Initials are just misleading the phonetic algorithm.

Comment: Identifying intials by length seems a fragile approach, though. Still, not my problem :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you're not just sorting by length, but you're also moving around the initials and surnames. How about this:

```
input.sortBy(_.length).map { name =>
    name.split(" ").sortWith(_.length > _.length).mkString(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
val res = input.sortBy(_.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val input = List("Rahul KM","M Ranjan","LK Advani")

var result = input.sortWith( _.length < _.length )

result.foreach( (s:String) => { println(s)} )
```